Calculate Hours Difference between two dates fields in Azure DevOps (ADO)
I need to set escalation mechanism for few SLA in my organization using ADO for the tasks created in ADO. I have two date fields, once is start date and other is end date (both of them are mandatory while creating the task).
Now everyday i need to calculate the difference of hours between the two date fields and accordingly send a notification from inside ADO only. Also, i want to change the back ground color of end date field if it is coming closer to end date & time.
How can i achieve this within ADO ?? I can do it easily by creating a webhook which then calls a Logic app workflow however the need is, not to perform anything outside ADO ?
regards,
AB
Solution how to achieve the calculation of hours between two date fields in ADO without bespoke / custom development.
